# Copy and rename resursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a structure as follows:

```
./tr-it/sitemap.html
./en-nl/sitemap.html
./fr-ca/sitemap.html
./it-it/sitemap.html
./fr-fr/sitemap.html
./tr-ir/sitemap.html
./en-it/sitemap.html
./en-us/sitemap.html
./en-kr/sitemap.html
./tr-ru/sitemap.html
./en-fr/sitemap.html
./en-int/sitemap.html
./en-tr/sitemap.html
./tr-us/sitemap.html
./tr-nl/sitemap.html
./en-ar/sitemap.html
./en-ir/sitemap.html
./en-se/sitemap.html
./es-us/sitemap.html
./en-ru/sitemap.html
./en-es/sitemap.html
./tr-es/sitemap.html
./es-ar/sitemap.html
./en-ca/sitemap.html
./pt-pt/sitemap.html
./tr-tr/sitemap.html
```

I need to copy and rename these files to the same directory as:

```
./en-us/sitemap.html to ./en-us/psitemap.html
./en-es/sitemap.html to ./en-es/psitemap.html
```

I tried variations of `find` and `exec` but no luck.

`find . -type f -name "sitemap.html" -printf "cp %p %p \n" | sed 's/sitemap.html$/psitemap.html\1/g'`

Here I tried to replace the last sitemap.html with psitemap.html and failed.

How can i copy and rename these files easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-execdir` option:

```
find . -type f -name "sitemap.html" -execdir echo mv {} psitemap.html \;
```

When satisfied with output, remove `echo` from above command.

Comment: Nice use of `-execdir`!

Comment: It isn't entirely clear, but it sounded like OP wanted to copy them with a new name, not just rename them in place.

Answer (score 4):

Use parameter expansion - substitution:

```
for file in ./*/sitemap.html ; do cp "$file" "${file/sitemap/psitemap}" ; done
```